# Where does the data get stored in Android (Using Xamarin) if there is no DB linked to it?

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

I am using Xamarin in visual studio. I have created an application that performs CRUD operations. I have not included any Database with my application in this case where will all my data which i enter will get saved..... Can some1 help me out in this???

Comment: where do you expect to store if not in a database?? otherwise it will be the nirvana.